# Can I call variables to the parameters of the method when I use them inside my method?

Tags: c#, java, methods

When I declare a method with parameters, and inside my method I assign value to those parameters, those parameters turn into variables?

My question is, can I Say:  "The parameter of my method is also a variable when I use it inside my method"?

Example:

```
public int returnDays(int month)
{
month = getMonth();
//"Can I say : month is a variable?"

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to assign to a parameter? It was passed by value, so the caller of `returnDays` will not see a change in whatever value he supplied. The parameter does not "turn into" anything it was not already because of your assignment. It is often more clear to introduce a new local variable rather than changing the value of a value parameter! Also: If you are not going to read the value the caller bothered to send you, what is the reason for having a parameter in your scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//"Can I say : month is a variable?"
```

yes it is a `local variable` to that method.

[Official docs on passing arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Thanks, and if I use month inside an if statement (inside of the same method) too?

Comment: Yes you can use it.Please spend some time on that link :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is called variable and you can call it variable and you can use it. Variable is a named place holder in memory whoes value could be changed in program

> In computer programming, a variable is a storage location and an
>   associated symbolic name (an identifier) which contains some known or
>   unknown quantity or information, a value. The variable name is the
>   usual way to reference the stored value; this separation of name and
>   content allows the name to be used independently of the exact
>   information it represents. The identifier in computer source code can
>   be bound to a value during run time, and the value of the variable may
>   thus change during the course of program execution, [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 questions

> I declare a method with parameters, and inside my method I assign
>   value to those parameters, those parameters turn into variables

Short Answer YES they are variables

> can I call variables to the parameters of the method when I use them
>   inside my method

As far as your context is concerned Yes you can use them but in a broader perspective what variables are accessible to you inside the method scope you should [**read**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) this before going in to development details

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely get your question. Yes, "month" is a variable. However, I'm unsure on what you're trying to achieve by assigning it.
The `int` type derives from `struct`, and this means that it isn't passed by reference. When you call `returnDays(x)`, `x` itself isn't passed and a copy of it is made.

If you, instead, wanted to change its value AND return the days, you'd need to use the `ref` or `out` keywords. The former basically passes a pointer to `x`, which can be used as your function pleases. The latter, however, is stricter and requires the function to initialize whatever value is passed through it.

So, this is the code you'd end up with

```
public int ReturnDays(out int month)
{
     month = GetCurrentMonth();
     return GetDays(month);
}
```

But still, I am not sure if this is the kind of answer you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is this C# or Java? Each language has its own eccentricities.

If C# use the out statement that KappaG3 showed.

If Java,

just use a return statement inside your function/method:

```
    return getMonth();
```

If you need to return multiple values, you can pass objects and then assign to those objects inside the function/method. Objects are passed by reference where as primitives are passed by value. integer is an Object but doesn't act like one as you can see from:

```
    //
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int      value1 = 0;
    Integer  value2 = new Integer(0);
    MyObject value3 = (new Main()).new MyObject(0);

    passByVal(value1);
    passByRef(value2);
    passByRef(value3);

    System.out.println("value1 = " + value1);
    System.out.println("value2 = " + value2);
    System.out.println("value3 = " + value3);
}

class MyObject
{
    public int value = 0;

    public MyObject(int value) { this.value = value; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value + "";
    }
}

public static void passByVal(int i)
{
    i = 7;
}
public static void passByRef(Integer i)
{
    i = new Integer(7);
}
public static void passByRef(MyObject o)
{
    o.value = 7;
}

}
```

which return the output:

```
0
0
7
```

so if you need to return a bunch of values I recommend passing objects or returning an object that is specially designed to hold all those values

Comment: except I probably should have made int value private instead of public and added a 
public int getValue(){ return value ;}
 to return the value

Comment: If you don't wish to create your own class, you could put all the values into a List or Arraylist, and you could even put mixed types into the list as long as you cast them back later. This is kind of a sloppy way to do it though and you will get compiler warnings unless you add the proper @supress